# Changing from Fahrenheit to Celsius in Weather Dash Plugin

Tags: unity, unity-dash

When you search for a city and enable the weather filter the weather is shown in Fahrenheit. How do I change this to Celsius.

Comment: what city? what is your regional format set to in settings - language support?

Comment: The country is set to India

Answer (score 22):

Open your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following command to change the temperature unit to Centigrade:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.GWeather temperature-unit "'centigrade'"
```

As can be seen in the image below, temperature is now shown in Centigrades:

[image: Temperature in Delhi shown as Centrigrade]

Alternatively, you can use [dconf Editor](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf Editor] to change the temperature unit and all the other Weather settings from a single place.

Navigate through *org* → *gnome* → *GWeather* in the sidebar. Then, change the `temperature-unit` and other settings as per your liking.

[image: Using the dconf Editor]

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly for me (the commands via `Terminal`)